# How to plot a correlation circle of PCA in Python?

Tags: python, pca

I was wondering how I can plot a correlation circle after a PCA.

I came accross this subject: [Plot a Correlation Circle in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815987/plot-a-correlation-circle-in-python).

But the code given in the answer doesn't plot the graph shown in the question message (which is what I want) but something else.

I also found out about a module called [Prince](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/prince/latest/prince.pdf) which is supposed to have a function plotting a correlation circle, but it's not working for me, I get an assertion error :

```
assert k > 0 
AssertionError
```

And here is my code (i got the dataframe from a SQL query and it's ok) :

```
pca = prince.PCA(df, n_components=2)
pca.plot_correlation_circle()
plt.show()
```

So, does anyone know how to use prince's PCA or simply how to plot a correlation circle in Python?

Comment: why not using the code from the link done in the answer of this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815987/plot-a-correlation-circle-in-python ??

Comment: Because I tried it but it's not doing a correlation circle, it draws one line per observation in a circle which is not what I want

Comment: maybe your not passing the right information as argument of this function, in the function `circleOfCorrelations(pc_infos, ebouli):` done by Mazieres (https://github.com/mazieres/analysis/blob/master/analysis.py#L19-34), you shouldn't pass the dataframe as argument, have a look more in detail, this function is called in the other function call `myPCA`. You can have a look at the example in comment at the end of the code

Comment: Yes you are right, it works, thanks :)